# Laplace Transforms Partial fraction

Tags: calculus

Use Laplace Transforms to solve

$ y" +  4y' + 5y = 1 $, with $y(0) = 1$ and $ y'(0) = 0 $

So far I have got $\frac{1}{p(p^2 + 4p + 5)}$

A friend of mine got this partial fraction into $\frac{1}{5p}- \frac{p+2}{5[(p+2)^2 + 1]} - \frac{2}{5[(p+2)^2 + 1]}$

How did he get that from my partial fraction?

Answer (score 2):

That's nothing more than $$\frac{1}{5p}- \frac{p+2}{5[(p+2)^2 + 1]} - \frac{2}{5[(p+2)^2 + 1]}= \frac 1{5p} -\frac{(p + 2) +2}{5(p^2 + 4p + 5)} =  \dfrac 1{5p} - \dfrac{p+4}{5(p^2 + 4p +5)}$$

The necessary set up to find coefficients needs only two fractions:

$$\frac A{p} + \dfrac {Bx + C}{p^2 + 4 p + 5}$$

Where $A = \frac 15, \;B = -\frac 15,\; C = \frac 45$.

What's nice about your friend's use of the equivalent $$\frac{1}{5p}- \frac{p+2}{5[(p+2)^2 + 1]} - \frac{2}{5[(p+2)^2 + 1]}$$ is the fact that the numerator for the second term is the derivative of its denominator, and the denominator (completing the square) of the third term is set up nicely for using the substitution $\tan u = p+2$.

Answer (score 1):

Something appears to have gone south with your result (and what you show your friend got).

The Laplace Transform produces:

$$s^2 y(s) - sy(0) -y'(0) + 4sy(s) -4y(0) + 5 y(s) = \dfrac{1}{s}$$

Substituting and simplifying yields:

$$y(s) = \dfrac{s^2+4s+1}{s(s^2+4s+5)} = \dfrac{4(s+4)}{5((s+2)^2+1))} + \dfrac{1}{5s}$$

This can be re-written as:

$$y(s) = \dfrac{4s}{5((s+2)^2+1))} + \dfrac{16}{5((s+2)^2+1))} + \dfrac{1}{5s} $$

using a [*Table of Laplace Transforms*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf), or do it using the Laplace defintion, we arrive at:

$$y(t) = \dfrac{8}{5} e^{-2t} \sin t + \dfrac{4}{5} e^{-2t} \cos t + \dfrac{1}{5}$$

Comment: I like your answer too! +1